# SSAS Tabular expression tables fail to load from SQL Server data source

Tags: ssas

We have been developing a new SSAS Tabular (1400) model, initially doing the PoC by loading the data directly from SQL Server (not using expressions). Once we had an idea of what we wanted, we refactored and did the data imports with Expressions to allow further Power Query (M) processing. At first, all seemed fine. Along the way we started to mash up other data from an ODBC datasource and didn't experience any issues during the process.

This morning we opened the project to make some modifications before running a new load of data and clicking "process tables" triggered an authentication dialog for the SQL Server data source again and then produced this error for all tables we were importing.

[image]

We have tried removing the data source connection string and adding it again. We removed all expressions and tried to start from scratch. No matter what we do, the Expression preview window WILL show the data preview, but attempting to import it into the model then fails with this error.

We've tried this on multiple workstations to try and rule out something with one developers settings that might have changed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After reading this error message again, it struck me that it mentions an ODBC error. The connection to the SQL Server database shouldn't be ODBC so that got me wondering if something was wrong with that connection instead. Sure enough, once I re-authenticated the ODBC data source, the data load worked as expected.

Note that we hadn't actually created a table in the model from the ODBC source yet. Regardless, processing the tables appears to try and validate each connection and rather than more clearly saying that something was wrong with this one data source (even though no data was being pulled into tables), the error dialog made it appear that the import was failing for the SQL Server connection, which is simply wrong.